# how to check the queries that are currently running in my mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out a way to know all the queries which are slowing my database. I used the command `SHOW PROCESSLIST`and it shows only BLOB under command section. How I can I see the actual queries which are taking most time and who is running them ?

Answer (score 3):

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G` should show you queries, users and source IP addresses.

Comment: The DB server is at remote location and I dont have access to it through SSH. I am using Workbench and it gives me syntax error whenever I try the command that you gave me.

Comment: Use a command-line client `mysql`? In Workbench you probably can not use the `\G` terminator. Just try leaving it out.