# MySQL query origination

Tags: mysql, reporting

Does anyone know if there is a way to figure out where a query is executing from?

I have a query that keeps failing and efforts to pinpoint it have failed.

I've setup query logging and everything, just can't find it.

Comment: 30 second search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391110/how-to-check-the-queries-that-are-currently-running-in-my-mysql-database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263453/retrieve-client-ip-address-in-mysql

Comment: guess I should have stated my question a little better... not the IP, but which php script is executing it.

Comment: Do you know the query string? If yes then there's nothing but searching the PHP code for that query, or a part of it. If you don't know the query then how do you know it's failing? What error does it trigger?

Comment: I have so many files, the site wasn't originally developed by me, I'm just doing some customization work on it; it works fine on the live version, but for some reason will not work on my local server. the query that is failing is...

`"select nUserId from es_sale  WHERE nSaleId ="`

and that's all I know.

Comment: The main problem is that the query inside the code would be something like this

`select nUserId from TABLEINDEX where nSaleId = "some php code"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... I located the query and put this as it's output so that I get a bit more information should it fail... I'll actually be applying this to all my queries.

```
function QueryResult($sql, $PVal) {
    if($sql != NULL) {
        $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql. 'in '.__FILE__.' '.mysql_error());
        return $rs;
    } //end if
    else {
        return '<b>MySQL Error</b>: Empty Query!';
    } //end else
}
```